# My JS animation execute all in the same time

Tags: javascript, css

i need my animation execute on scroll down, and restart when the user scroll down after scroll up, for some reason the animation execute when refresh the page all in the same time, not has the user is scrolling.

I need the animation execute has the user scrolling down.

Will show here the code

```
const item = document.querySelectorAll("[data-anime]");

const animeScroll = () => {
    const windowTop = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight * 0.85 ;

    item.forEach(element => {
        if (windowTop > element.scrollTop) {
            element.classList.add("animate");
        } else {
            element.classList.remove("animate");
        }
    });
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", ()=>{
    animeScroll();
})
```